# How can I add a source root in a packaged Grails 2 plugin?

Tags: grails, plugins, groovy

I have a plugin that uses precompilation on some of its classes. What I mean by this is that I have a source directory at `src/precompile` with various Groovy files in it, and I do the following (plus some logging and exception handling and stuff):

```
// in _Events.groovy
eventCompileStart = {
  // Compile these files first
  groovyc(srcDir: getPluginDirForName('my-lib').path + '/src/precompile', 
    destdir: pluginClassesDirPath,
    classpathref: 'grails.compile.classpath', 
    encoding: projectCompiler.encoding, 
    verbose: projectCompiler.verbose)
}
```

This works fine for testing the plugin and for including it as an in-place plugin via `grails.plugin.location.'my-lib' = '../MyLib'`. However, I am now packaging up the library to serve it via Artifactory, and including it no longer works properly.

Say MyProject uses MyLib via:

```
// in BuildConfig.groovy
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
  plugins {
    compile(':my-lib:1.2.3')
  }
}
```

The library gets downloaded and installed fine, but if I have a class in MyProject that references a precompiled class in MyLib (i.e, one whose source resides in `src/precompile/ca/mycompany/mylib/` in the plugin's source tree) the compiler can't resolve it and I get compilation errors. I noticed that if I expand the view of the plugin in the Grails View of IntelliJ the precompile directory is not marked as a source root. If I manually mark it as such the project compiles but I don't want to have to do that every time.

So here's my question: is there some way to programmatically mark this directory as a source directory? It looks like by default only the `src/groovy` directory is marked as source. I've looked through the various metadata files included in the .zip file but I haven't found any way to add `src/precompile` as a source root.

Comment: I've also been looking for a way to do this.